# Laravel create new records error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a few Form on create different records with different validation rules.

My route (web.php) file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

  Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

  Route::get('/home/info/create/{id}', 'InfoController@create');
  Route::post('/home', 'InfoController@store')->name('home');
  Route::get('/home/info/delete/{id}', 'InfoController@delete');

  Route::get('/home/odbor/create/{id}', 'OdborController@create');
  Route::post('/home', 'OdborController@store')->name('home');
  Route::get('/home/odbor/delete/{id}', 'OdborController@delete');


  Route::get('/home/zamestnanec/create/{id}', 'ZamestnanecController@create');
  Route::post('/home', 'ZamestnanecController@store')->name('home');
  Route::get('/home/zamestnanec/delete/{id}', 'ZamestnanecController@delete');

  Route::get('/home/program/create/{id}', 'ProgramController@create');
  Route::post('/home', 'ProgramController@store')->name('home');
  Route::get('/home/program/delete/{id}', 'ProgramController@delete');
});
```

Creat, store, delete function : 
(function is simillar in all controller)

```
public function create(Fakulta $id)
{
    return view('create.info', compact('id'));
}

public function store(CreateInfoRequest $request)
{

    Info::create($request->all());

    return redirect('home');
}

public function delete($id)
{
    Info::where('id',$id)->delete();
    return redirect('home');
}
```

And problem is, when I want create new e.g. Info (/home/info/create) after touch submite button I get validation errors. On validation is using file specified in last Controller from middleware group (ProgramController@store) and I don't know why. But when I move Route::post('/home', 'InfoController@store')->name('home'); on last line of group or create new program (/home/program/create) everything is OK.

Easier:

After touch submit button is dont use this file

CreateInfoRequest.php file:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'event_date' => 'required|date|after:today'
    ];

}
```

but this one :
CreateProgramRequest.php

```
   public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required',
        'titul' => 'required',
        'length' => 'required',
        'forma' => 'required',
        'typ'=> 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'fakulta_id'  => 'required',

    ];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with below changes:

Put route as:

```
Route::post('/home/info/store', 'InfoController@store')->name('infoStore');
```

**Instead of**

```
Route::post('/home', 'InfoController@store')->name('home');
```

Because you create same post route for all so just change route and try its may be solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I edit all Route::post and all 'url' in Form::open. It is running

Comment: @Bando if my answer is your solution then please upvote to my answer